# Как работает функция, помогите разобраться

Tags: c, строки

Читаю книгу. В ней описана такая ф-ция: (Взято из книги *"Программирование: введение в профессию. II: низкоуровневое программирование", автор Андрей Викторович Столяров.*
Функция сравнения строки с образцом ("*" в образце означает любое к-во символов в строке, "?" - любой символ в строке)

```
int match( const char *str, const char *pat)
{
  int i;
  for(;; str++, pat++){
    switch(*pat){
      case 0;
        return *str == 0;
      case '*':
        for(i=0; ;i++){
          if(match(str+i, pat+1))
            return 1;
          if(!str[i])
            return 0;
        }
      case '?':
        if(!*str)
          return 0;
        break;
      default:
        if(*str != *pat)
          return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Помогите понять, как именно данная ф-ция сравнивает звездочку. (Например str = "Karasik", pat = "*sik". Если я правильно прочитал и понял прочитаное, то функция должна вернуть`int > 0` (то есть `True`), если так, то **как ф-ция обрабатывает звездочку?**, объясните пожалуйста).

P.S.: Мои рассуждения (str = "Karasik", pat = "*sik"): Вход -> `match(str, pat)` -> `case '*'` -> `i=0` -> `match(str+0, pat+1)` -> `default` -> `(*str == 'K') != (*pat == 's')` -> `return 0` -> `(возвращаемся в for(i;;i++) цикл)` -> `(match(str+0, pat+1) вернул 0, а значит сработает if(!str[i]) и вернет 0` -> Конец. (это не очень похоже на `int > 0`)
**Где я ошибся?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну давайте посмотрим..

```
Karasik    *sik
```

Тот самый ваш цикл. Сравнение (рекурсивной - той же функцией!)

```
Karasik    sik
```

Не прошло? идем дальше, `i = 1`

```
arasik     sik
```

Не получилось? Пробуем еще, `i = 2`

```
rasik      sik
```

И так, пока не получим совпадение (в данном случае - когда `i=4`) или не исчерпаем строку...

Так понятнее?

Ваша главная ошибка - вы решили, что

```
if(!str[i]) return 0;
```

сразу, при `i==0` вернет 0. Но при `i==0` получается `str[0]=='K'`, так что это - ненулевое значение; его отрицание (`!`) даст нулевое значение, и `if` не сработает - он сработает только на завершающем строку нулевом символе.

Comment: Да, да, спасибо вам, уважаемый. И почему я мог подумать, что `str[0] == 0`, ведь все же очевидно. Спасибо еще раз. :-)